# Laravel API not detected

Tags: rest, authentication, mobile, laravel, laravel-4

I am building a mobile application that I want to authenticate its users through my Laravel web application.

So far I have the following:

`APIController.php:`

```
/**
 * Authenticate mobile user.
 * GET /api/auth
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function postAuth()
{

//  Extract the authentication credentials.

    $input_email = $_POST["email"];
    $input_password = $_POST["password"];

    if(Auth::attempt(array('email'=>$_POST["email"], 'password'=>$_POST["password"])))
        {
    // Authentication returns true
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

        return Response::json(array(
            'status' => 'true',
            'user' => $user->toArray())
        );

    } else {
    // Authentication returns false
        return Response::json(array(
            'status' => 'false'
            );
    }

}
```

`Routes.php:`

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function()
{
    Route::post('auth', 'APIController@postAuth');
});
```

Basically, I am wanting to test if I can login by passing a username and password value to Laravel. I am using:

```
curl --user testagent@email.com:password http://localhost:8888/api/auth
```

The error it returns is ridiculously long:

I think I've figured out the error - changing my `Route` to `GET` instead of `POST` returns the error `Email variable cannot be found`, which makes sense. As soon as I change the route back to `POST`, it cannot be found? Even using cURL presents the same error.

There will be numerous `GET` and `POST` requests as this is just the start of my app!

Any help would be hugely appreciated as to the best practices or where I'm going wrong. Many thanks.

Comment: Post the error here.

Comment: We are talking like a thousand lines long, @NoahMatisoff. It's trying to compile a page by the looks of things, and an example snippet is: `"request_headers":"array(6) [\n    'user-agent' => array(1) [\n        string (11) \"curl\/7.28.1\"\n    ]\n    'host' => array(1) [\n        string (14) \"localhost:8888\"\n    ]\n    'accept' => array(1) [\n        string (3) \"*\/*\"\n    ]\n    'php-auth-user' => array(1) [\n        string (19) \"testagent@email.com\"\n    ]\n    'php-auth-pw' => string (6) \"******\"\n    'authorization' => array(1)`

Comment: I think I've figured out the error, it's a HTML page of the generic `Controller cannot be found`, which relates to /api/auth. That route is a `POST`, though, so it shouldn't be accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide which Authentication type you want to use.

**auth.basic**

The auth.basic login is the implementaion of  a simple [HTTP Login](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) in Laravel.
This is not suitable for an API as this method *displays* a small window where the user should type his credentials.n (You can also send the credentials via cURL but most APIs work with the normal method.)
This method is also a little bit harder to customize.

In Laravel the core which "makes" this method is implemented in **app/filters.php**. Which as the [documentation in the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php#L259-L278) states just uses HTTP Basic Auth.

or

**normal login**

When using the normal login method, with `Auth::attempt()` you have to make sure, that the tables for the user mangagement are created and the model `User` exists.

The normal login method gives you the ability to customize your login process a lot more than the standarf HTTP method, which i explained above.

To use this method, just remove the filter (`'before' => 'auth.basic'`) on your route.
When using that method, you also have to put your User Data in the Request Payload, as you want to read it from there while using `$_POST`.

Example:

`curl --data "username=testagent@email.com&password=password" http://localhost:8888/api/auth`

This normal login flow is the best practice as its a little more secure and easier to customize as the HTTP Login.

I hope you understand what i mean, if you have any questions just comment and i will try to clarify my answer.

Comment: Hi @Reflic, thank you for your reply. Using your example returns a really long error, however, changing it to `curl --user "email=testagent@email.com&password=password" http://localhost:8888/api/auth` then asks for a `host password for user`, which I'm unsure of. I can confirm my `User` model exists and it is currently authenticating my actual web application.

Comment: Have you removed the filter? 'before' => 'auth.basic'

Comment: You used --user instad of --data in the curl statement.

Comment: I am using --user instead of --data. It asks to enter the host password for user after I submit the cURL script. The error message looks like the HTML page for `Controller cannot be found`, as if the /localhost:8888/api/auth isn't accessible?

Comment: I changed the POST into GET within the route and it found it straight away. The error it returned was undefined `email` variable, which makes sense. Changing it back to POST returns the same controller cannot be found error, after asking for a 'host password'.

Comment: You have to use --data! That is another error which does not correlate with that error. Maybe try using -X POST as a option for curl. If my answer could help you please mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry Reflic, I misread your initial comment. It returns everything perfectly! Much appreciated. Thank you again.